# k-medoids on binary data

Tags: binary-data, k-medoids

I have a binary dataset and I would like to cluster it with the k-medoids algorithm. The dataset is not huge: I have 10 dimensions and around 250 objects. I am clustering physical infrastructures given some structural characteristics, which may be present or not. If they are present, the object is associated to a higher risk of developing a failure, therefore the cluster analysis is a kinf od explanatory analysis which I do in order to understand which groups of objects could be associated to higher risk. The category (1/0) should be treated simmetrically. I choose k-medoids because in my work I have to perform often cluster analysis with mixed dataset (numerical, categorical, binary). However, sometimes the dataset could be only binary or only categorical. For me it is very practical to use the same algorithm for each analysis. Does it make sense in your opinion to cluster binary data with the k-medoids algorithm? If not, which algorithm do you suggest me? In general, which information of my clustering problem is relevant in order to choice the proper cluster algorithm?
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: If you have mixed data types you need to use a different appropriate distance metric, it's not an issue with k-medoids, which also accepts only numeric types.

Comment: I am using the PAM algorithm in R with the Euclidean distance. I also calculate the Silhoutte Width in order to identify the optimal number of clusters. Which distance would you suggest?

Comment: Have a look at Gower distance.